# Running vscode extension tests from the command line

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a VS Code extension for which I am preparing continuous integration. Unit tests have been added and I can successfully run them interactively within VS Code. The output appears in an OutputChannel.

Documentation says that vscode extension tests can be launched from the command line. This assumes that the current folder is the root of the extension workspace.

```
code --disable-extensions --extensionDevelopmentPath . --extensionTestsPath src\test\runTest.ts
```

VSCode launches and then exits again, but results do not appear on the console.

#### How does one determine the outcome of the tests?

Are the results going into logs, and if so what determines the location of the log files?

If not log files then how?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: Alas, nothing yet!

Comment: I found out that my tests were not running at all. I randomly tried to disable the other extensions with `--disable-extensions` and it worked! You can add this flag in runTest.ts: 
`await runTests({ extensionDevelopmentPath, extensionTestsPath, launchArgs: ["--disable-extensions"] })`